# Python Flask: View a different image on button click

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, api, flask

I am new to learning python and working with APIs, I am trying to retrieve a random image from an API endpoint and render to a webpage, using Python flask, I am able to do that, I just need the image to update to a new image when I click a button.

When I click the button, I get a html 200 code on the console but the image don't change

This is my main.py

```
    ''' from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
i

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def next_image():
    response_api = requests.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?api_'
                                'key=API-KEY')
    data = response_api.json()[0]['url']
    return render_template("index.html", cat_image=data)


@app.route("/getimage")
def get_img():
    cat_img = next_image()
    return cat_img


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
'''
```

my html code

```
 ''' <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Random Cats Images</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Random Cat Images</h1>

        <input type = "button" id = "mybutton" value = "View Next "/>
    <div>
       <img src="{{cat_image}}" id="myimg" alt="Cat Image">
    </div>

    </body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#mybutton').click(function(){
           $.ajax({
           url: "{{ url_for ('get_img') }}",
           type: "GET",
           success: function(response) {
               $("#myimg").attr('src', response.url);
          },
         });
       });
    });
  </script>
</html>


 '''
```

Comment: What happens when you click the button? If you get an error, include the error (in your post; not in comments). Where is the definition for ```next_image``` ?

Comment: @NoCommandLine Thanks for your reply, I have edited the post, I get a 200 success code but the image won't change

Answer (score 1):

Your code for `next_image()` makes a call to an API which presumably returns a list of images and your code always picks the first one in the list - `response_api.json()[0]` i.e. your index is `0` which is the first item in the list.

With your current code, the only way you will get different images is if each call to your API returns a different list of images or the images are ordered differently.

If your API call is returning the same list, then you will need to use something like a global index value to determine which image to return i.e. something like this

```
curr_index = 0

app = Flask(__name__)

def next_image():
    global curr_index
    response_api = requests.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?api_'
                                'key=API-KEY')

    
    data = response_api.json()
    
    # If curr_index is outside of the list index, then raise an error
    if curr_index == len(data):
        return "Sorry, no more images"
    
    # Use curr_index to pick which image in the list to return
    data = data[curr_index]['url']

    # Increment curr_index so that next time you call, you pick a different image in the list
    curr_index = curr_index + 1

    return render_template("index.html", cat_image=data)
```

Note: This is just an example. There are other ways (might be more efficient) to tackle this